# how to add leading zeros to the mobile number and dates of births less than 10

Tags: excel, vba

I have been having issues with a script of mine and cant figure out how to add leading zeros to mobile numbers and days less than 10.

This script takes values from an excel spreadsheet and puts them into an online form for me but i am having to manually add the zeros at the minute which i dont want to have to do.

I have tried altering the spreadsheet to add the zeros to no avail so i was wondering if there was anything i could do in this script to add them as it goes?

Here is the script im using (recorded with WinTask):

```
Dim title$(100)
Dim name$(100)
Dim surname$(100)
Dim postcode$(100)
Dim number$(100)
Dim email$(100)
Dim Ts$(100)
Dim Flatno$(100)
Dim Houseno$(100)
Dim Street$(100)
Dim Locality$(100)
Dim Town$(100)
Dim County$(100)
Dim Dpostcode$(100)
Dim Company$(100)
Dim DHouseno$(100)
Dim Dstreet$(100)
Dim Dlocality$(100)
Dim Dtown$(100)
Dim Dcounty$(100)
Dim dd$(100)
Dim mm$(100)
Dim yyyy$(100)
Dim cardname$(100)
Dim cardtype$(100)
Dim cardno$(100)
Dim securityno$(100)
Dim expmm$(100)
Dim expyyyy$(100)
Dim manufacturer$(100)
Dim Handset$
Dim Price$(100)
Dim tariff$(100)


ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","R2:R90", title$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","S2:S90", name$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","T2:T90", surname$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","Y2:Y90", postcode$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","D2:D90", number$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","U2:U90", email$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AG2:AG90", Ts$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","Z2:Z90", Flatno$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AA2:AA90", Houseno$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AB2:AB90", Street$())  
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AC2:AC90", Locality$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AD2:AD90", Town$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AE2:AE90", County$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AH2:AH90", Dpostcode$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AI2:AI90", Company$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AJ2:AJ90", Dhouseno$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AK2:AK90", Dstreet$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AL2:AL90", Dlocality$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AM2:AM90", Dtown$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AN2:AN90", Dcounty$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","V2:V90", dd$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","W2:W90", mm$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","X2:X90", yyyy$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AF12", cardname$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AG12", cardtype$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AH2", cardno$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AI2", securityno$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AJ2", expmm$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","AK2", expyyyy$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","F2:F90", manufacturer$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","BD2:BD90", handset$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","E2:E90", price$())
ReadExcel("datadel.xlsx","BE2:BE90", tariff$())

#Actiontimeout=60

i=0
repeat

StartBrowser("IE", "[blank]", 3)

UsePage("Order Management Login")
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'User[username]']", "[blank]")
WriteHTML("INPUT PASSWORD[NAME= 'User[password]']", "[blank]")
ClickHTMLElement("INPUT SUBMIT[VALUE= 'Login']")

UsePage("Affiliate Login Area")
pause 2 secs
ClickHTMLElement("A[INNERTEXT= 'Sales Portal']")


UsePage("Sales Portal")
pause 2 secs
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'productUrlName']", manufacturer$(i))
pause 2 secs
ClickHTMLElement(handset$(i))
pause 2 secs
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'tariffCode']", price$(i))
pause 2 secs
ClickHTMLElement(tariff$(i))
pause 2 secs
ClickHTMLElement("A[INNERTEXT= 'BUY']")

UsePage("[blank]")
ClickHTMLElement("INPUT IMAGE[SRC= 'https://media.secure']")
SelectHTMLItem("SELECT[NAME= 'personal_title']", title$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'personal_first_name']", name$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'personal_last_name']", surname$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'address_postcode']", postcode$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'personal_phone_dayti']", number$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'personal_phone_eveni']", number$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'personal_email']", email$(i))

SelectHTMLItem("SELECT[NAME= 'personal_date_of_bir']", dd$(i))
SelectHTMLItem("SELECT[NAME= 'personal_date_of_birth_m']", mm$(i))
SelectHTMLItem("SELECT[NAME= 'personal_date_of_birth_y']", yyyy$(i))
ClickHTMLElement("DIV[OUTERTEXT= 'If you do not wish to be contacted with our   latest offers then please check the box.']")
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'personal_existing_nu']", number$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'promo']", ts$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'address_flat']", flatno$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'address_house_number']", Houseno$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'address_street']", Street$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'address_locality']", Locality$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'address_town']", Town$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'address_county']", County$(i))


ClickHTMLElement("INPUT CHECKBOX[NAME= 'delivery_preferred']")

WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'work_number']", number$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'delivery_postcode']", Dpostcode$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'delivery_flat']", Company$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'delivery_house_numbe']", DHouseno$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'delivery_street']", Dstreet$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'delivery_locality']", Dlocality$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'delivery_town']", Dtown$(i))
WriteHTML("INPUT TEXT[NAME= 'delivery_county']", Dcounty$(i))


ClickHTMLElement("INPUT IMAGE[SRC= '[blank]',INDEX='2']")

ClickHTMLElement("A[HREF= '[blank]',INDEX='2']")

pause 4 secs


closebrowser()

i=i+1
until manufacturer$(i)=""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Format` function for example with an English mobile phone number:

```
Format(strNumber, "00000 000 000")
```

The same function can be used for a leading 0 on other numbers:

```
Format(intDays, "00")
```

See: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When I want leading zeroes I use a combination of String(,) and Right$.  See this sample.

```
Sub T()

    Dim number As Long

    number = 10

    Const lLeadingZeroes As Long = 5

    Dim sLeadingZeros As String
    sLeadingZeros = Right$(String(lLeadingZeroes, "0") & CStr(number), lLeadingZeroes)

    Debug.Print sLeadingZeros


End Sub
```